# Adding a Meteor Chart to an existing Kinetic.JS app

Tags: kineticjs, meteorcharts

I'm building a game with kinetic.js and I want to display some line charts using Meteor Charts within it. The chart needs to scale with the game canvas and be positioned correctly.  Can I embed the chart directly in an existing layer within the app?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1) layer the MeteorCharts visualization on top of the KineticJS stage like this

```
<div id="kineticjs-container"></div>
<div id="meteorcharts-container"></div>
```

2) if you don't need interactivity, you could convert the MeteorCharts data viz into a KineticJS image and then add it to your KineticJS layer like this

```
lineChart.stage.toImage({
    callback: function(img) {
        kineticLayer.add(new Kinetic.Image({
            image: img
        });
    }
);
```

3) if you need interactivity, you should also be able to move the MeteorCharts layers into your KineticJS stage, something like this:

```
lineChart.stage.getChildren().each(function(layer) {
    // remove the layer from the MeteorCharts KineticJS stage
    layer.remove();

    // add the layer to your own KineticJS stage
    kineticStage.add(layer);
});
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.  Whenever MeteorCharts updates its layers, it will actually be updating the layers on your stage since objects are modified by reference in JavaScript

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'm using #3 which is what I need but it's only partially copying to the stage. The Grid, Title and Legend appear to be moved correctly however the plotted lines and background remain in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying the individual nodes from each Meteor layer to an existing group within my Kinetic.JS stage.

```
 var group = new Kinetic.Group();
 lineChart.stage.getChildren().each(function(layer, index) {
   layer.getChildren().each(function( node ) {
     group.add( node );
   });
 });
```

This results in the chart being positioned correctly however none of the events for interactivity work. Are the events attached to the Meteor Stage?